# Different results on local machine than on corenlp.run though using same annotators

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Following this question: 
[Why does 'corenlp.run' yield different results when I run CoreNLP locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539527/why-does-corenlp-run-yield-different-results-when-i-run-corenlp-locally)

I still see different results on my local machine dependency graph than on corenlp.run. I am using 3.7.0 version and this code:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
    graph =  sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedPlusPlusDependenciesAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence?

Comment: "ASCL info service is growing slower"

My dependencies are: [service/NN -> ASCL/NN (compound), service/NN -> info/NN (compound), growing/VBG -> service/NN (nsubj), growing/VBG -> is/VBZ (aux), growing/VBG -> slower/JJR (xcomp)]

So for example growing->slower is (xcomp) while crenlp.run is (advmod)